# History of the phrase "olden days"

Tags: etymology, history

When and where was the phrase *olden days* coined?

Comment: I think the original (or at least, more widespread) was **olden times**. But both are now hopelessly archaic, and for some reason more recent 'facetious' usage tends to favour *days* over *times*. But I see no prospect of meaningfully identifying a "first coinage" for what were both probably just normal use of language in **days of yore**, as I would call them when I'm in retro-whimsical mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Google's [Books Ngram Viewer](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=olden%20days,olden%20times&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), the phrase was coined some time around 1800 and peaked around 1930:

[image: Ngram]

The oldest reference I could find for "olden days" is the 1805 [*Tobias: a poem : in three parts* by Rev. Luke Booker](http://books.google.com/books?id=heQ-AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA1&dq=%22olden%20days%22&hl=en&ei=YthKTrj7CMfJsgamr9GsBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22olden%20days%22&f=false):

[image: olden days]

And the oldest I found for "olden times" is [*Poems on Affairs of State from 1620 to this Present Year 1707*](http://books.google.com/books?id=3SYJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA258&dq=%22olden%20times%22&hl=en&ei=aNtKTueJA8bBswb9h_i1Bw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22olden%20times%22&f=false), in a poem called "GIGANTOMAXIA, or a full and true Relation of the Great and Bloody Fight between three Pagan Knights and a Christian Giant" by an unknown author and originally published in 1682:

[image: olden times]

I suspect these stem from the [Romantic era](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanticism):

> Romanticism is a style of art, literature and music in the late 18th
>   and early 19th century in Europe. This movement said that feelings,
>   imagination, nature, and old folk traditions such as legends and fairy
>   tales were important. In part, it was a reaction to the aristocratic
>   social and political ideas of the Age of Enlightenment and the
>   Industrial Revolution. It was also a reaction against turning nature
>   into a mere science. It showed itself most strongly in arts like
>   music, and literature.

Take for example this 1868 poem called [The Olden Days](http://books.google.com/books?id=314CAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA241&dq=%22olden%20days%22&hl=en&ei=PtJKTumhGM2KswbZlITCBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22olden%20days%22&f=false).

Comment: In 1600, Early Modern English was still being used. What if it was just spelled differently then? (So as not to show up in that form in the corpus?)

Comment: This is probably as good an answer as we'll find, I expect "olden days" is a common enough phrase to be hard to track, as FumbleFingers had mentioned.

Comment: @simchona Possible, but I tried a few spellings and didn't hit on anything. I've added in "olden times" which was more popular but follows a similar trend.

Comment: @Hugo cool--I didn't mean to nitpick, but I've made the "if it's not on NGrams, it wasn't invented" mistake

Comment: I don't think the nGram is a reliable indicator of the start of usage. It seems to show 1800 merely because that's when the bulk of the corpus starts.

Comment: This is what you get from using nGram instead of a real dictionary.  See [the OED entry](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130964), where you’ll find that it dates back to *Cursor Mundi*. It’s also in *Piers Ploughman* and Shakespeare.

Answer (score 11):

The phrase is a good deal older than the other answer suggests. It’s already found (as *olden dawes*) in *Cursor Mundi*, specifically, in the ms. Trinity College R.3.8: 'Now com my sawes Þat I seide bi olden dawes'. [This entry](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED30499&egs=all&egdisplay=open) in the Middle English Dictionary dates that citation to ante 1400 and offers another from ~1426. Before that we find it in Old English  'in olden days', e.g., in the [*Life of St Æðeldryþ*](http://faculty.virginia.edu/OldEnglish/anthology/aethel_t.html) in Ælfric of Eynsham’s *Lives of Saints* (late 10th century), in Ælfric’s *Homilies*, and in the charter [S 1146](http://ascharters.net/charters/1146?q=&page=) from 1062x66.

Comment: I *knew* there had to be some older use! (+1ed already)

Comment: I suspect the `-en` ending is an archaic dative, which would be correct with prepositions like in or bi (by). In modern German, the expression "in olden days" still has the same ending: "in alten Tagen". In fact, one of the pages cited by Brian also reports the Old English form "on ealdum dagum", with the original dative ending "-um", which was later reduced to "-en", and finally disappeared in Modern English.