# "Old days" or "olden days"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adjectives, suffixes

Sometimes I use the phrase "back in the *old* days". I was recently in a class where the trainer kept using the phrase "*olden* days." Which usage is acceptable?

Comment: *Olden* is itself archaic - including it in a reference to bygone times is just whimsical (*bygone* being another archaism, of course! :) Actually, that may not be strictly true - *olden* may be a (whimsical) Victorian "mock-olden" word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers On the contrary, if you would please look at the *OED* entry, you’ll find that *olden* has a long history, and is certainly not a Victorian neologism.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't doubt *olden* has a long and venerable history - I was really just alluding to the fact that *"in olden times"* became comparatively popular in the second half of C19, [eventually displacing](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+olden+times%2Cin+old+times&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) the originally more common *"in old times"*. But *"in olden times"* is a "set phrase", whereas *"in olden days"* is quite unusual, and OP had best avoid it if he doesn't want raised eyebrows.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I completely agree that this is a set phrase, but don’t you think the set-phrase formula is “in olden XXX”, for various values of *XXX* including both “days” and “times”? Both seem perfectly equally normal (or abnormal) to me. I don’t perceive the *times* version as being any more or less common than the *days* version myself. But perhaps that’s just me.

Comment: @tchrist: ["in olden days"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+olden+days%2Cin+old+days%2Cin+olden+times%2Cin+old+times&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) is the least common variant with *"in"*, and with *"the"*, everything except ["the old days"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+olden+days%2Cthe+old+days%2Cthe+olden+times%2Cthe+old+times&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) virtually flatlines. I think *"in olden days"* is the "set phrase", for *"olden"* - anything else is "errors" caused by people being unfamiliar with the usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’m not particularly interested in what books Google has or has not managed to scan in accurately. People put far too much trust in a dodgy source like nGrams, especially for historical accuracy and completeness, where it is quite well known to suffer greatly; no scholarship there at all.  In contrast, the OED cites both *olden days* and *olden times*.  Are you actually trying to say that the *OED* is wrong? It also gives a few other examples.  [Kindly consult the full OED entry](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130964).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2493/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-tchrist)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can’t.  Chat won’t load. Sorry.

Comment: @tchrist: Perhaps it'll work later. I think ELU keep those things for at least a week or two. No matter for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Old days" is possibly more correct — but "olden days" is a common saying.

[History of the phrase "olden days"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38185/history-of-the-phrase-olden-days)

Comment: That’s not really a very good history of the phrase.  See the *OED*.

Answer (score 1):

If one consults [the *OED* entry for ‘olden’](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130964),  one learns that ‘olden’ dates all the way back to *Cursor Mundi* itself, hardly a Victorian tome. It’s also in *Piers Ploughman* and Shakespeare.

> **Pronunciation**:  Brit.  /ˈəʊld(ə)n/, U.S.  /ˈoʊld(ə)n/
>
> **Forms**:  ME holden, ME holdon, ME oldyn, ME– olden, 18 aulden (*Sc*.).
>
> **Etymology**:  Probably originally an inflected form of **old** *adj*., although subsequently perhaps understood as showing **old** *n.<sup>2</sup>*  + **-en** *suffix<sup>4</sup>.*
>
> > Phrases similar to *olden days*  were common in both Old and Middle English. Old English had the phrase *(on) ealdum dagum*  (compare **old** *adj*. 9a), with dative plural ending *-um* . In Middle English, such phrases often preserved archaic forms. For example, from early Middle English onwards the phrase *(bi) olde dawe*  is attested, where the noun has an archaic plural form (compare γ forms at **day** *n.*), but the adjective has the regular marked *-e*  form. In late Middle English *(bi) olden dawes, (in) holdon daw*  (see quots. *a*1400  and *c*1426), archaic forms of the plural noun persist (*day*  usually having a regular plural form elsewhere in both texts), suggesting that the phrase had become a fixed formula. Their *-en*  element could conceivably be the reflex of the Old English dative plural ending *-um*, accidentally not attested during the intervening period (although *-en* is very occasionally found as a plural inflection of this word in other senses in early Middle English); but an alternative explanation, possibly more consistent with the non-attestation of *-en* forms earlier, would be that the trisyllabic structure of the fixed phrasal unit was preserved by means of the replacement of unstressed *-e* (normally lost in this position) by *-en* (protected in medial position before a homorganic consonant). From fixed phrases like *in olden days* the word was perhaps generalized in early modern English to other contexts.
>
> Now chiefly literary.
>
> orig. and chiefly ***in olden days, olden time(s)***. Belonging to a past age or time; ancient, old; (also) aged.
>
> - *a*1400  (1325)       *Cursor Mundi* (Trin. Cambr.) 18100      Now com my sawes Þat I seide bi olden dawes.
> - 1401       *Inquisition Misc.* (P.R.O.: C 145/279/1) m. 1,      Mesuagium vocatum the Oldyn.
> - *c*1426       J. Audelay *Poems* (1931) 20      Þe goodys of hole cherche‥Þat oþer han ȝeuen in holdon daw.
> - *a*1500  (1376)       Langland *Piers Plowman* (Eaton) A. xɪ. 303      Holden [c1400 *Trin. Cambr.* austyn þe olde].
> - 1576       G. Gascoigne *Steele Glas* (Arb.) 58      In olden dayes, good kings‥Contented were, with pompes of little pryce.
> - *a*1616       Shakespeare *Macbeth* (1623) ɪɪɪ. iv. 74      Blood hath bene shed ere now, i' th' olden time.
> - 1682       S. Speed *Gigantomaxia* 5      A Town it has, which Fiends Inchant, Where Brideled Furies Roar and Rant, In olden times, hight *Troynovant, But now 'tis London Stiled.*
> - 1768       D. Garrick in *False Delicacy* Epil.,      In olden times your grannams unrefin'd, Ty'd up the tongue, put padlocks on the mind.
> - 1791–2       Wordsworth *Descr. Sketches* 147   There an old man an olden measure scanned On a rude viol.
> - 1816       Scott *Tales my Landlord* 1st Ser. Introd.,      A young person‥who delighted in the collection of olden tales and legends.
> - 1823       Byron *Don Juan: Canto XII* xliii,      Olden she was—but had been very young.
> - 1866       J. Smith *Poems* 205      Wi' pith o' aulden days, Sing loudly [etc.].
> - 1904       J. Conrad Nostromo i. i. 2      Many adventurers of olden time had perished.
> - 1970       M. McLuhan *Let.* 30 Apr. (1987) 405      The elderly love to recall and the children love to hear about the ‘olden times’.
> - 1995       M. Amis *Information* (1996) 434      All he could see was a single sandy suede shoe‥: the olden hushpuppy of R.C. Squires.

The proper citation for that entry is:

> olden, adj.
>
> Third edition, March 2004; online version December 2011. < http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130964 >; accessed 14 February 2012. An entry for this word was first included in *New English Dictionary*, 1902.

Answer (score 1):

The trivia tidbit that is missing here is that 'old' in ME was also a noun meaning old folks "the olden'' or ancient times. 
*Send æfter þine wiue & æfter þine children, þan ᵹungen & þan **olden**.*

It was also a plural adjective. Why does this plural form still stand when *ouren* (our) and *eyen* (eyes) fell out? (But *oxen* stayed.) It may be owing to the fact that it was both a plural noun and a plural adjective form ... or it just may be that folks liked it!

Answer (score 1):

In the Viking Old Norse language and in present-day Scandinavian languages, "the" is represented by adding "en" to the end of the word.

Olden seems to come from this usage, so "in olden days" has the same meaning as "in the old days."  You would not say "in the olden days" because "the" is already represented by "en."

Even though this is English and not Old Norse, I think this rule should apply.

Comment: Good point, both about the origin and the usage.

Answer (score 0):

(Literary) If you refer to a period in the past as the olden days, you feel affection for it. We had a delightful time talking about the olden days on his farm. ...the nicely painted railways of olden times.

tip

1. In the olden days or in olden days means in the past. In the olden days the girls were married young.

by the app of dictionary.com